# Geolocation - UK places with 100,000 people within a 30 mile radius

Tags: data-request, uk

I have a bunch of locations in a google fusion table, I've also got a population density spreadsheet from The Guardian so I have some data on population density.

But I was wondering if there was a data set that would give me the locations (postcodes, whatever) that were within 30 miles of, say, 100,000 people in the UK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this Q&A at GIS SE ([Worldwide population density data not grouped by country](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24435/worldwide-population-density-data-not-grouped-by-country)) (updated by me to reflect link changes):

> One of the best gridded data sets is CIESIN's Gridded Population.
>
> See [Gridded Population of the World (GPW), v3](http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/collection/gpw-v3#aboutTable) for more details. The best resolution is 30 Arc seconds (*The global data set has resolution of 2.5 arc minutes - Deer Hunter*).

To find the places, have a look at this question at GIS SE: [Algorithm for finding population for a given center point and radius in US](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16358/algorithm-for-finding-population-for-a-given-center-point-and-radius-in-us)

In general, I would advise looking for geospatial data at GIS Stack Exchange before going here. The chances are quite high the question has already been asked and answered there.

EDIT: through gracious assistance of **ldodds**, UK-specific reverse geocoding facility (at Ordnance Survey) has been identified:

http://beta.data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/datasets/os-linked-data/explorer/search

with documentation available at http://beta.data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/docs/search. This would be the last stage in the processing pipeline.

Comment: You could also look at combining this with some data from the Ordnance Survey. For example, if you find the lat/long of populations of 100,000 people using the data that Deer Hunter suggest, you could then relate this back to UK locations, including places, post-codes, etc using the search API on the beta OS Linked Data site: http://beta.data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/datasets/os-linked-data/explorer/search. Docs, including notes on geo search, are here: http://beta.data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/docs/search

Comment: @ldodds - thanks, this qualifies as an answer, since I provided only worldwide data. OS data are somewhat more detailed.

Comment: Its not a complete answer though as the OS data doesn't have the population data, seems like a mixture of the data sources would work. Feel free to revise your answer to include it :)